# Minimum directional derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I know that maximum of $(D_uf)= ||grad f||$

Because $(D_uf)= grad f. u = ||grad f||.||u||.Cos\theta$

So how about the minimum value? I believe it must be $-||gradf||$ since $min(cos\theta = -1 ) $but my note says it's just $||gradf||$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I agree with you. If the min equals the max, it means that f is flat and $D_{u}f =0$